# Why doesn't this emberjs template update?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm learning emberjs and I've done a pretty simple example. The HTML template is:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Hello <b>{{App.appOwner}}</b>
</script>
```

And then the javascript is:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  appOwner : 'Erik'
});


App.appOwner = 'Tom';
```

Which does pretty much what you expect. The emberjs.com documentation says templates are auto-updating -- so I added this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  console.log('HERE!');
  App.appOwner = 'Alphonse';
});
```

Which quite unexpectedly failed. I had added the console.log just to make sure the click handler was being called, which it was. Why doesn't it update?

Comment: What if you use `App.set('appOwner', 'newvalue');`?

Comment: @zerkms apparently that does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.set()` mutator method, because javascript doesn't have facilities to intercept the direct properties changes:

```
App.set('appOwner', 'Alphonse');
```